# aiboデベロッパーサイトのサンプルコードを実行する方法

Tags: api, aibo-developer

aiboデベロッパーサイトのサンプルコードに書かれているソースの一部を、所持aibo のトークンとデバイスＩＤに書き換えた後、どうすればパソコンで実行出来るのでしょう？

持っているのは windows10 のＰＣとAndroidのスマホです。
さくらレンタルサーバー・プレミアムです。でもPythonのバージョンが 2.7 のようです。
Python を Windows10 home にインストールする必要がありますか？

ネットを探すとクラウド上で実行出来るような記述もあり、Python でも色々な種類やバージョンがあるようで、開発環境を構築するには、何をどうすれば良いのか判りません。

よろしくお願いいたします。

**追記**
コードそのものを載せて良いのか判りませんが、リンクは構わなさそうです。
サンプルコードは下リンクの「Introduction」項目の「APIの実装例」にあります。
https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python のコードを実行するには必ず Python のインストールが必要です。ご認識の通り複数のバージョン、大きく分けて **2.x** と **3.x** の二種類とがありますが、(実行されたい)サンプルコードには特に記載がないので、今回は 2.x をインストールすればよさそうです。(3.x が必要になった場合でも両者は共存可能です)

Windows 向けのインストーラは [公式サイトのダウンロードページ](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) から、"Latest Python 2 Release" のリンクからダウンロードしてみてください。
インストール自体は画面の指示に沿って進めるだけですが、コードの実行方法など含め詳しくは解説書や解説サイトが色々とありますので、それらを参考にしてもらった上で、もしわからない点があれば改めて別の質問として投稿してみてください。

Comment: 2.x を勧める理由はありますか……？ Python 2.x は2020年1月1日に[End of Lifeする](https://pythonclock.org/)ので、特に制約が無ければ 3.x で良いと思うのですが。

Comment: 私自身は Python にそこまで詳しくないため、2.x を強く勧める理由はありませんが、質問の目的としては「サンプルコードを動かす」の様なので 3.x で動かなくて 2.x を入れ直す…よりは無難そうな 2.x を勧めた次第です。 / 純粋に Python の学習を目的としているようであれば、3.x を勧めたと思います。